# Is there a python library to generate STL file for 3D printing?

Tags: python, rapid-prototyping

I am currently in a project where a lot of 3D printing designs need to be done. They are all parameterized, so I'd like to write a python code to generate those design files (in .STL format) for me. I was wondering that, is there a python package that can do this? Because currently I am all doing those by hand using SolidWorks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is... It's called FreeCAD.

The assembly module is already in the devel version (as of 06/15/2014) and will be of production quality really soon for real assemblies!

http://freecadweb.org/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, more than one.

In my humble experience, I tried many Open Source tools for parametric CAD modeling using Python (FreeCAD, Rhino-Grasshopper, Blender, Salome). 
All of them are valid options and the best one is represented by your ability to either model or code.

I recently favour SALOME (www.salome-platform.org) because of the straight forward "dump study" option, the continue development and the good API documentation.

Particularly I did some 3d prints using the exportSTL command once I had a solid worthy of printing and it was ok.

Nevertheless, if you intend to work on surfaces rather than solids, I don't think you will find anything worthy Open Source (Rhino has a little price to pay).

Answer (score 0):

There is also a new one ! called [pymadcad](https://github.com/jimy-byerley/pymadcad)

It's a library meant to do complete CAD stuff only with python scripts.
At contrary to FreeCAD, Pymadcad is natively dealing with triangular meshes so it makes it very easy to import/export .stl files.

There is a growing amount of surface generation functions (extrusion, revolution, tube, screw, smooth surface, ...). And there is also all the stuff to generate and deal with 3D primtives such as Lines, Arc, ...

[Here is a brief look at the features](https://pymadcad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html)

Comment: Your link 'Here is a brief look at the features' points to an HTML file in your local filesystem. Please replace it by a normal server URL reachable for everybody.

Comment: ooops, you are perfectly right. I fixed it.